# mean stack: ccavenue form is not posting in

Tags: express, nodes, mean-stack, ccavenue

Actually I am integrating the ccavenue payment gateway in meanstack application, 
according to: https://github.com/KalaiselvanMahendran/ccavenue/blob/master/server.js

but when I am trying  to call this from my express js its not redirecting to payment gateway page 
I am trying like

```
ccavenue.setMerchant("xxxx")
ccavenue.setWorkingKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
ccavenue.setOrderId("xxxxxxxx")
ccavenue.setRedirectUrl("xxxxx.xx")
ccavenue.setOrderAmount("5000")
var param = {
     billing_cust_address: 'Bangalore', 
     billing_cust_name: 'Nitish Kumar'
};
ccavenue.setOtherParams(param)
ccavenue.makePayment(res)
```